# MYSQL query that selects from filters

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a product filter feature. Each product could have an arbitrary number of filters.

I have set up my table like so:

```
row_id products_id filters_id 
     1           1          1 
     2           2          2 
     3           3          3 
     4           4          3 
     5           1          3
```

So the table has a list of product_ids and corresponding filter_ids. As this seemed like such a simple table, I assumed that the script would be easy. But I am really struggling to get my head around it.

There query I got to, was:

```
SELECT p.products_id
     , p.products_name
     , p.products_short_desc
     , p.products_price
     , p.products_url
     , p.products_image
     , p.products_short_desc
     , p.contact_pricing
     , GROUP_CONCAT(ptc.categories_id) category_id 
  FROM products p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN prod_to_cat ptc 
    ON ptc.products_id = p.products_id 
   AND ptc.categories_id IN (3) 
 WHERE p.products_status = 1
 GROUP 
    BY p.products_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ptc.categories_id) = 1 
 ORDER  
    BY p.products_price
```

As an example, if just one filter was selected, and it was id 3. This failed to work properly, even with much tweaking. It also seems fair to complex, for something I thought would have been so simple.

So essentially, I am trying to work out how, with this table, can I select all the products, that have all the match filters_id's?

So if  if filter 1 and 3 were selected, I would want to yield the results of all products that match, i.e. are in the table with their product id and corresponding filter_ids. In this example, it would just return products_id 1, if just filters id 3 was selected it would return product 3,4 and 1. How is this achieved?

Comment: So if filter 1 and 3 were selected the output would display row id 1,3,4,5?

Comment: No, its not an OR, its an AND. so if filters 1 & 3 were selected only products_id 1 would be displayed. E.g. you want a red dress, size Medium, not red dresses or medium dresses.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, is the filter applied to more than one column (property) of the object?

Comment: So what's wrong with your query, except of using wrong table (`prod_to_cat`) and/or wrong column (`ptc.categories_id IN (3)`)?

Comment: Because IN() uses OR, I want AND.

Comment: Ok so I can see that everyone else also finds this quite complicated too

Comment: What is the name of the filter table?

Comment: It is prod_to_cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems fairly straightforward to me:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_filters;

CREATE TABLE product_filters
(product_id INT NOT NULL
,filter_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product_id,filter_id)
);

INSERT INTO product_filters VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,3),
(1,3);

SELECT product_id 
  FROM product_filters 
 WHERE filter_id IN(1,3) 
 GROUP 
    BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+

SELECT product_id 
  FROM product_filters 
 WHERE filter_id IN(3) 
 GROUP 
    BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
+------------+
| product_id |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          3 |
|          4 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the full query so I can test it?

Comment: Based on the data set provided, THAT would be the full query. If you want a fuller answer, ask a fuller question! My answer should serve as an example.

Comment: OH! So it works by showing rows that have a count the same as the number of filters? That's really clever.

Comment: So I just need to work out how to join the products table as well, and it should be rocking